# Add double quotes to variable name for MS Deploy code in c#

Tags: c#, string, ssis, msdeploy

Its a c# code written in a SSIS script task component.

> PS_script + @"""$compname = " **"\" + Row.computername"\"** +
>   "$appname =" + Row.applicationname + "  $appvalue = " + Row.appvalue +
>   "";

I am tying the MS deploy and setting params coming from table driven. The above statement throws error as I am not able to pass double quotes in **computername** param.

Comment: Can you add a expected result?

Comment: PS_script = PS_script + @""" $compname = ""PAPRDSPTAPP"" $appname = ""IIS Web Application Name""$appvalue = """;  

This

Comment: `PS_script += " $compname = \"" + Row.computername + "\" $appname = \"" + Row.applicationname + "\" $appvalue = \"" + Row.appvalue + "\"";`

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

In C#, a literal string with the prefix `@`, `""` will be replaced by `"`.

Example :

```cs
var str = @"$compname = """ + Row.computername + @"""";
```

If the variable `Row.computername` has the value `SERV01`, then the result will be :

```
$compname = "SERV01"
```

You can also escape a character with `\`. Then `\"` will be replaced by `"`.

Example :

```cs
var str = "$compname = \"" + Row.computername + "\"";
```

If the variable `Row.computername` has the value `SERV01`, then the result will be :

```
$compname = "SERV01"
```

In you case, you can also use `string.Format` to more lisibility :

```cs
string.Format(
    @" $compname = ""{0}"" $appname = ""{1}"" $appvalue = ""{2}""",
    Row.computername, Row.applicationname, Row.appvalue
);
```

Warning, with SSIS script task, you can't use string interpolation (the literal string prefix `$`).

Comment: Basically this did not work. somewhere i need the string to in the below format  
`"$msdeploy = \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\IIS\\\\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\\\msdeploy.exe\"\n            $package = \"\"\n            $compname = \"GRAVITAS_VM02\"\n            $appname = \"IIS Web Application Name\"\n            $appvalue = \"C:\\Deploy\\Test\\Test.zip"`

Comment: $msdeploy has 4 Backslash as path's separator and $appvalue has only 2. Is it desired?

Comment: Yes. I am building it up in c# language.  These compayname , application are all derived from db and will append from string variables.